# Open() and codecs.open() in Python 2.7 behave strangely different

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, codec, python-unicode

I have a text file with first line of unicode characters and all other lines in ASCII.
I try to read the first line as one variable, and all other lines as another. However, when I use the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import os
filename = '1.txt'
f = codecs.open(filename, 'r3', encoding='utf-8')
print f
names_f = f.readline().split(' ')
data_f = f.readlines()
print len(names_f)
print len(data_f)
f.close()
print 'And now for something completely differerent:'
g = open(filename, 'r')
names_g = g.readline().split(' ')
print g
data_g = g.readlines()
print len(names_g)
print len(data_g)
g.close()
```

I get the following output:

```
<open file '1.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x01235230>
28

7

And now for something completely differerent:

<open file '1.txt', mode 'r' at 0x017875A0>

28

77
```

If I don't use readlines(), whole file reads, not only first 7 lines both at codecs.open() and open().

Why does such thing happen?
And why does codecs.open() read file in binary mode, despite the 'r' parameter is added?

Upd: This is original file: http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/0792d687

Comment: `codecs.open()` *has* to open the file in binary mode to prevent bytes that *look* like newlines being interpreted before decoding. UTF-16 newlines are `\n\x00` or `\x00\n` for example.

Comment: It'd help if you shared your original input file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Thank you for your answer! Here is the file: http://wikisend.com/download/406380/1.txt

Comment: It's a bug, as observed by Wooble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052971/python-codecs-fails#comment26421813_18052971

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you used `.readline()` *first*, the `codecs.open()` file has filled a linebuffer; the subsequent call to `.readlines()` returns *only* the buffered lines.

If you call `.readlines()` *again*, the rest of the lines are returned:

```
>>> f = codecs.open(filename, 'r3', encoding='utf-8')
>>> line = f.readline()
>>> len(f.readlines())
7
>>> len(f.readlines())
71
```

The work-around is to not mix `.readline()` and `.readlines()`:

```
f = codecs.open(filename, 'r3', encoding='utf-8')
data_f = f.readlines()
names_f = data_f.pop(0).split(' ')  # take the first line.
```

This behaviour is really a bug; the Python devs are aware of it, see [issue 8260](http://bugs.python.org/issue8260).

The other option is to use [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead of `codecs.open()`; the `io` library is what Python 3 uses to implement the built-in `open()` function and is a lot more robust and versatile than the `codecs` module.

Comment: Great! I have checked, and sizes of `code`''.join(data_f)'`code` and `code`''.join(names_f)`code` are nearly equal.