# Python codecs fails

Tags: python, encoding

I'm experiencing a weird error (or is it a bug?) with the [python codecs module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html). I'm using Python 2.7.4.

Suppose I want to read the following file called `foo`:

```
0
aaaa
bbbb
cddd
dddddddd

Long sentence here which is not even read completely

The rest is ignored...
```

I use the following code for that:

```
import codecs
log = codecs.open('foo', encoding='utf8')
log.readline()
lines = log.readlines()

print ''.join(lines)
```

The result I get is

```
aaaa
bbbb
cddd
dddddddd

Long sentence here which is not even read com
```

As you see, the file is not read entirely!?!! Is there any explanation for that?

(The problem does not occur if I omit the call to "readline", or if I don't use any encoding... This is all very mysterious to me.)

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem. I would like to see a reference to the codecs documentation, though. This behaviour of readline/readlines is completely insane, isn't it?

Comment: The behavior observed here, and described in that link, is in contradiction with the official documentation for files, which states that a plain `file.readlines()` would read until EOF.  It looks like a bug of codecs, or possibly a missing warning in the documentation if there is any reason for keeping it working that way.

Comment: @ArminRigo I have exactly the same impression. +1

Comment: For what it's worth, it's a known bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue8260

Comment: @Wooble brilliant! Basically, that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!