# How to read the rest of the lines? - python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file and it has some header lines, e.g.

```
header1 lines: somehting something
more headers then
somehting something
----

this is where the data starts
yes data... lots of foo barring bar fooing data.
...
...
```

I've skipped the header lines by looping and running `file.readlines()`, **other than looping and concating the rest of the lines, how else can i read the rest of the lines?**

```
x = """header1 lines: somehting something
more headers then
somehting something
----

this is where the data starts
yes data... lots of foo barring bar fooing data.
...
..."""

with open('test.txt','w') as fout:
  print>>fout, x

fin = open('test.txt','r')
for _ in range(5): fin.readline();
rest = "\n".join([i for i in fin.readline()])
```

Comment: readlines() reads the entire file.  Calling it in loops makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.readlines()` reads **the all data in the file**, in one go. There are no more lines to read after the first call.

You probably wanted to use `.readline()` (no `s`, singular) instead:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as fin:
    for _ in range(5): fin.readline()
    rest = "\n".join(fin.readlines())
```

Note that because `.readlines()` returns a list already, you don't need to loop over the items. You could also just use `.read()` to read in the remainder of the file:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as fin:
    for _ in range(5): fin.readline()
    rest = fin.read()
```

Alternatively, treat the file object as an iterable, and using [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) slice the iterable to skip the first five lines:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('test.txt','r') as fin:
    all_but_the_first_five = list(islice(fin, 5, None))
```

This does produce *lines*, not one large string, but if you are processing the input file line by line, that usually is preferable anyway. You can loop directly over the slice and handle lines:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as fin:
    for line in list(islice(fin, 5, None)):
        # process line, first 5 will have been skipped
```

Don't mix using a file object as an iterable and `.readline()`; the iteration protocol as implemented by file objects uses an internal buffer to ensure efficiency that `.readline()` doesn't know about; using `.readline()` after iteration is liable to return data further on in the file than you expect.

Comment: ah there is a catch, `readlines()` only read up till an empty line.

Comment: @alvas: If you have a file object that behaves differently, you are either adding data at the end or you've found a bug in the buffer handling of the file object in question.

Comment: it's a bug i think, i check the `len(open(infile,'r').readlines())` and it's far far bigger than `len(readline())x5` + `readlines()`

Comment: @alvas: Yes, `codecs` has that bug; let me dig that up for you.

Comment: @alvas: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130904/open-and-codecs-open-in-python-2-7-behave-strangely-different/16155098#16155098

Comment: @alvas: I'd use `io.open()` instead of using `codecs` to read unicode from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the first 5 lines:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    data = list(islice(fin, 5, None))
    # or loop line by line still
    for line in islice(fin, 5, None):
        print line
```